# Underscore.js: Filter array of objects, then sort by average?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have an array of data like the following, sorted by month ascending:

```
[{
  org_id: "K83002",
  percentile: 1,
  date: "2013-11-01",
},
{
  org_id: "K83059",
  percentile: 33,
  date: "2013-12-01",
},
{
  org_id: "K83607",
  percentile: 22,
  date: "2013-12-01",
} ...
```

I want to create a sorted list of organisations, ranked by their mean percentile position over the latest three months in the data.

Right now, I'm doing this:

```
            var lastThreeMonths = _.uniq(_.pluck(data, 'date'), true).slice(-3);
            var averages = {};
            var lastMonths = _.each(data, function(d) {
                if (_.contains(lastThreeMonths, d.date)) {
                    if (d.org_id in averages) {
                        averages[d.org_id] += d.percentile;
                    } else {
                        averages[d.org_id] = d.percentile;
                    }
                }
            });
            var temp = [];
            for (var k in averages) {
                temp.push({ 'org_id': k, 'percentile': averages[k]});
            }
            var sortedAvgs = _.sortBy(temp, 'percentile').reverse();
```

But this is extremely verbose. Is there a nicer way to do it?

Ideally I'd also like to attach the raw data for each organisation the sorted array, somehow, because I'm going to iterate over the sorted array next, and it would be convenient to access the data inside that iterator.

Comment: Can you show a little more of the input and what output it should generate?

Answer (score 1):

This should help you:

```
// Create a hash of allowed dates - much improved performance over arrays for larger data sets
var lastThreeMonthsHash = _.chain(data).pluck('date').uniq().slice(-3).map(function (date) {
    return [date, true]
}).object().value();

// filter out older entries
var grouped = _.chain(data).filter(function (monthly) {
    return lastThreeMonthsHash[monthly.date];
    // group by org_id
}).groupBy('org_id').map(function (values, orgId) {
    // reduce each group into a single value which is the average percentile
    var percentiles = _.pluck(values, 'percentile');
    var sum         = _.reduce(percentiles, function (memo, value) {
        return memo + value;
    }, 0);
    return {
        org_id    : orgId,
        percentile: sum / values.length
    };
    // sort by percentile & reverse
}).sortBy('percentile').reverse().value();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
var sortedAverages = _.chain(data)
  .filter(d => _.contains(lastThreeMonths, d.date))
  .groupBy('org_id')
  .map(eachOrg => {
    var average =  _.sum(_.pluck(eachOrg, 'percentile'));
    return {
      org_id : eachOrg.org_id,
      percentile : average
    };
  })
  .sortBy('percentile')
  .value()
  .reverse();
```

Comment: Thanks! This is nice and compact, but I'm not sure how to rewrite it for pre-ES6 compatibility. Also, where does `eachOrg` come from?

Comment: eachOrg is actually a function argument. Read up on ES6 arrow functions. If you make it in es5 it would look like : ```function(eachOrg){ /* ... */}```